# A word for something that is different but believably similar?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

I think the word I’m looking for starts with a P (not parody). Also, I think this word has a second meaning: similar, but disconcertingly so, and nominally a la ‘uncanny valley. I have tried Googling the answer and could only find this [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384833/a-word-for-something-familiar-but-in-reality-not), but the answers were not suitable and the context was different—-those answers include:

- Deceptively similar (two words, and I am quite sure there is a single alternative)
- simulacrum (too uncommon, no agreeded upon definition, and could possibly sound orotund in certain contexts)

However, its first paragraph is useful:

‘Specious would be a great analogy to the word I'm looking for. It is something that it is true on the surface but really is not, i.e. superficially familiar, but not if we look closely’

Example sentences:

1. ‘Satire or parody is at its best when the imitation is believable. The characters or writing should only be a slight _________ of the real material.’
2. ‘Disneyland castle is a _________ of a real palace.’
3. My British friend told me that ‘The TV show ‘The Crown’ is a bad imitation of British royalty, as it belittles it and is a complete _______ of reality.’

Comment: are you looking for *perversion*?

Comment: @Jim Yes! I actually just remembered the word 2 minutes after posting. I am very impressed that you found the correct answer, as the similarity I spoke of is only implied. Also, the second meaning is, of course, actually its primal meaning. I also incorrectly characterised the word I was looking for.  Bravo!

Comment: You can post an answer for your own question.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking because it's not clear if you're referring to an intentional dissimilarity to the original, an imperfect attempt at duplicating the original that's unintentionally dissimilar, or a coincidence of uncanny similarity. As such, I wouldn't use the same word for all three examples, like for the first, I *might* use "**perversion**," but it **has a distinctly negative connotation**, so if I didn't intend that, I might use "exaggeration" instead, whereas for the second sentence, I wouldn't use "perversion" at all but use a word like "knock-off" or "imitation."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker answered their own question in an edit.

Comment: Performed rollback to remove the edit containing the answer, and added it as a community wiki answer, which I think is the more appropriate way to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

As posted by the OP (originally in an edit):

I found the word: **perversion**.
I'll leave the post up though, as others might find it helpful.